# Не могу вывести объект на экран из БД в Angular

Tags: c#, база-данных, angular, .net-core

Решил посмотреть, что такое Angular 12 и как он работает с .NET Задача вроде бы простая, но ничего не получается: нужно всего лишь вывести на экран объекты из БД, но я получаю пустоту.
Вот на этой странице хочу вывести:

```
<div class="bg-secondary p-5 rounded-lg m-3 text-light">
<div class="display-4 text-center">Payment Detail Register</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <app-payment-detail-form></app-payment-detail-form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 pt-4">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Card Owner</th>
                <th>Card Number</th>
                <th>Exp. Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let pd of service.list">
                <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.cardOwnerName}} 
        </td>
                <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.cardNumber}}</td>
                <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.expirationDate}} 
         </td>
                <td><i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger" 
                (click)="onDelete(pd.paymentDetailId)"></i></td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Вот здесь я создаю обращение к БД

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { PaymentDetail } from './payment-detail.model';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class PaymentDetailService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  formData: PaymentDetail = new PaymentDetail();
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:1960/api/PaymentDetail'

  list: PaymentDetail[];

  postPaymentDetail() {
  return this.http.post(this.baseURL, this.formData);
  }

  putPaymentDetail() {
  return 
  this.http.put(`${this.baseURL}/${this.formData.paymentDetailId}`, 
  this.formData);
  }

  deletePaymentDetail(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`);
  }

  refreshList() {
  this.http.get(this.baseURL)
   .toPromise()
   .then(res => this.list = res as PaymentDetail[]);
  }
 }
```

В дальнейшем нужно реализовать функции на удаление и изменение объекта, но соответственно оно не работает. Что-то не так с моим массивом list: PaymentDetail[];

Я только учусь всему этому делу, поэтому нашел видео с таким уроком, но там используют Angular 11, а у меня установился Angular 12. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему. Ибо на собеседованиях часто спрашиваю, как связать фронтэнд с базой данных, а я не могу этого сделать, у меня выходит пустота. Заранее спасибо!

добавил файл компонент

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
     import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
     import { PaymentDetail } from '../shared/payment-detail.model';
     import { PaymentDetailService } from '../shared/payment- 
     detail.service';

     @Component({
     selector: 'app-payment-details',
     templateUrl: './payment-details.component.html',
     styles: [
     ]
     })
     export class PaymentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(public service: PaymentDetailService,
     private toastr: ToastrService) { }

     ngOnInit(): void {
      this.service.refreshList();
     }

     populateForm(selectedRecord: PaymentDetail) {
 this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, selectedRecord);

     }

     onDelete(id: number) {
     if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?')) {
      this.service.deletePaymentDetail(id)
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            this.service.refreshList();
            this.toastr.error("Deleted successfully", 'Payment Detail 
         Register');
          },
          err => { console.log(err) }
         )
       } 
      }
     }
```

еще один компонент

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { PaymentDetail } from 'src/app/shared/payment-detail.model';
import { PaymentDetailService } from 'src/app/shared/payment-detail.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-detail-form',
  templateUrl: './payment-detail-form.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class PaymentDetailFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: PaymentDetailService,
    private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (this.service.formData.paymentDetailId == 0)
      this.insertRecord(form);
    else
      this.updateRecord(form);
  }

  insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.postPaymentDetail().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.service.refreshList();
        this.toastr.success('Submitted successfully', 'Payment Detail Register')
      },
      err => { console.log(err); }
    );
  }

  updateRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.putPaymentDetail().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.service.refreshList();
        this.toastr.info('Update successfully', 'Payment Detail Register')
      },
      err => { console.log(err); }
    );
  }

  resetForm(form: NgForm) {
    form.form.reset();
    this.service.formData = new PaymentDetail();
  }

}
```

Comment: А где у вас вызов запроса к БД. Если он у вас есть, то что приходит  в консоли браузера? Добавьте еще ts-файл компонента. Возможно у вас еще есть ошибка в консоли, если она есть, то можно поискать самостоятельно решение или добавить в вопрос

Comment: В html обращаетесь к `pd`, а в классе продекларирован `list`

Comment: Вижу обращение к полю list, но не вижу, где вызывается метод `refreshList`, который заполняет лист

Comment: Sergey Glazirin
 вот добавил файл компонент

Comment: В html поменяйте pd на list

Comment: Alexander Chernin    не проходит компиляцию даже...
       <td (click)="populateForm(list)">{{list.cardOwnerName}}</td>
                                                          ~~~~

  src/app/payment-details/payment-details.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './payment-details.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component PaymentDetailsComponent.